# What does the light pinkish color indicate on the 'Questions' page?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't find anywhere what the light pink background color for some questions is about.

[image]

Comment: Hey Daniel! Can you make it more clear what you're talking about, specifically? I don't see any pink in that image. We're fond of freehand red circles here.

Comment: @Catija Probably a form of colorblindness, or the hue settings on his monitor aren't adjusted correctly.